# Transform 2d array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i need a function that transforms a 2d array from:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

to

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

my first approach was by transforming the matrix with

```
array_unshift($data, null);
call_user_func_array('array_map', $data);
```

But now i got:

```
1 5
2 6
3
4
```

Can someone help?

Edit: 
Ok let me be more clear i have these categories and i need to reorder them in this way

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Das ist los
            [1] => Land & Leute
            [2] => Wirtschaft & Politik
            [3] => Leben
            [4] => Kultur
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chronik
            [1] => Motor
            [2] => Sport
            [3] => Blaulicht
            [4] => Schauplatz
        )

)
```

I need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Das ist los
            [1] => Wirtschaft & Politik
            [2] => Kultur
            [3] => Motor
            [4] => Blaulicht
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Land & Leute
            [1] => Leben
            [2] => Chronik
            [3] => Sport
            [4] => Schauplatz
        )

)
```

Comment: Can we have proper `var_dump($array)`?

Answer (score 2):

For a simple 2-column array:

```
$myArray = [
    [1,4],
    [2,5],
    [3,6],
];

$myNewArray = array_chunk(
    array_merge(
        array_column($myArray, 0), 
        array_column($myArray, 1)
    ), 
    2
);
var_dump($myNewArray);
```

**EDIT**

For a more generic solution:

```
$myArray = [
    [1,6,11],
    [2,7,12],
    [3,8,13],
    [4,9,14],
    [5,10,15],
];

$columns = count($myArray[0]);

$tmpArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $columns; ++$i) {
    $tmpArray = array_merge(
        $tmpArray,
        array_column($myArray, $i)
    );
}

$myNewArray = array_chunk(
    $tmpArray, 
    $columns
);
var_dump($myNewArray);
```

Comment: First thank you for help. I added some more details. 
My array is more like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and i need transform to [[1,3,5][2,4,6]]